# PHP class as argument

Tags: php, class, static, arguments

Is it possible to do this?

```
class Foo
{
    public function __construct($bar)
    {
        $barish = new $bar();
        $barish->woo();
    }
}

class Bar
{
    function woo()
    {
        echo "wooooo";
        die();
    }
}

// Here the magic should happen
$foo = new Foo(Bar);
```

I expect `wooooo` but I get "Use of undefined constant Bar".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `''`:

```
class Foo
{
    public function __construct($bar)
    {
        $barish = new $bar();
        $barish->woo();
    }
}

class Bar
{
    function woo()
    {
        echo "wooooo";
        die();
    }
}

// Here the magic should happen
$foo = new Foo('Bar');
```

Comment: This is the right solution at the moment. But it is damn ugly to pass a classes name as string to a function... not only for type hinting and refactoring reasons. I want something like the [`Type`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) from C# please :D . The `Type`-solution is just so smooth and opens up sooo many possibilities.